# IOS report crash

Tags: ios, crittercism

I'm using crittercism to get the crash report from my ipad app.
What i need is to check if the app was crashed last time loaded at startup.

I'm using the CrittercismDelegate that contains crittercismDidCrashOnLastLoad on the appDelegate of my app but it seems does not work !!

any example/suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Rob, one of the co-founders of Crittercism.  That's a known bug that we're releasing a fix for early next week!

We will be adding some more info on our support page shortly:

https://www.crittercism.com/developers/feedback